# noUiSlider conflicts with Joomla

Tags: joomla, conflict, nouislider

I'm a noob but I was able to build this: https://www.gloeckle.de/landing/0custom/nouislider/test.html

But when I try to integrate that into my Joomla site and click the slider the height of the slider is set to 0px. Just try for yourself. I gave every id and class a prefix ("lp_") but still no luck.

Anyone knows what the problem here is? --> https://www.gloeckle.de/landing/skl/gewinnchance-bestimmen

Thanks in advance for any help!
getimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because of mootools javascript framework , that adding some functionality on slider and ...
you can disable mootools in some page in your joomla with something like this

Mootools Enabler/Disabler
http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/mootools-enabler-disabler

Answer (score 0):

It so happens that there is a method called "slide" in mootools and your plugin too!

If you rename it to something else, it might just work out for you.

The same issue was encountered with the jquery UI slider some time back and was reported.

Link for reference: [Ticket](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4168)

Or you may also try the workaround given by them.